# How to merge JavaScript object array using reduce?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

There's so many of post here regarding merging javaScript array objects relative to my question most of them are merging 2 arrays in my case it's different.

I have JSON from API I mapped and filtered them because i only need the 'tags'

Here's my code:

```
JSON.map((key) => (key.tags))
.filter(function (element) {
    return element !== undefined;
})
```

Here's my result:

```
   [ 
      { 
    "web_devt": { 
      "item_id": "858850847", 
      "tag": "web_devt" 
    } 
  }, 
  { 
    "web_devt": { 
      "item_id": "1004644524", 
      "tag": "web_devt" 
    } 
  }, 
  { 
    "pdo": { 
      "item_id": "1056300113", 
      "tag": "pdo" 
    }, 
    "php": { 
      "item_id": "1056300113", 
      "tag": "php" 
    }, 
    "web_devt": { 
      "item_id": "1056300113", 
      "tag": "web_devt" 
    } 
  }, 
  { 
    "parallax scrolling": { 
      "item_id": "1087678088", 
      "tag": "parallax scrolling" 
    } 
  }, 
  { 
    "react": { 
      "item_id": "2435593852", 
      "tag": "react" 
    } 
  }, 
  { 
    "javascript": { 
      "item_id": "2435595088", 
      "tag": "javascript" 
    } 
  }, 
  { 
    "react": { 
      "item_id": "2465629468", 
      "tag": "react" 
    } 
  } 
]
```

I want to merge them like this:

```
[
{
"web_devt": [
    item_id: "765558416", 
        item_id: "765558416",
        item_id: "765558416",
        ...]
},
 {
"react": [
    item_id: "765558416",
    item_id: "765558416",
    item_id: "765558416",
    ...]
},
{
"JavaScipt": [
    item_id: "765558416",
    item_id: "765558416",
    item_id: "765558416",
    ...]
}
```

]

and so on ...
Basically all the same tags will merge
How you do this in reduce or any solution but not loadash or any third party?

Comment: Your desired output's syntax is invalid. Arrays do not have key-value pairs, only values.

Comment: @Shidersz, the second suggesstion you gave is also invalid since you cannot have multiple keys  of the same name in an object

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri You are right, I wish I can edit my comment still, but I will have to delete instead...

Comment: @Shidersz You could delete and add the relevant part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your desired output syntax is invalid. You cannot have an array with keys nor you can have an object with multiple keys of the same name.

However if you want have an array of ids, you could use reduce and group the data and for the individual item use [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to get the key and the value within the object.

```js
var data = [ 
  { 
    "web_devt": { 
      "item_id": "858850847", 
      "tag": "web_devt" 
  } 
  }, 
  { 
    "web_devt": { 
      "item_id": "1004644524", 
      "tag": "web_devt" 
    } 
  }, 
  { 
    "pdo": { 
      "item_id": "1056300113", 
      "tag": "pdo" 
    }, 
    "php": { 
      "item_id": "1056300113", 
      "tag": "php" 
    }, 
    "web_devt": { 
      "item_id": "1056300113", 
      "tag": "web_devt" 
    } 
  }, 
  { 
    "parallax scrolling": { 
      "item_id": "1087678088", 
      "tag": "parallax scrolling" 
    } 
  }, 
  { 
    "react": { 
      "item_id": "2435593852", 
      "tag": "react" 
    } 
  }, 
  { 
    "javascript": { 
      "item_id": "2435595088", 
      "tag": "javascript" 
    } 
  }, 
  { 
    "react": { 
      "item_id": "2465629468", 
      "tag": "react" 
    } 
  } 
] 

const res = data.reduce((acc, item) => {
  Object.entries(item).forEach((attr) => {
    const [key,value] = attr;
    if(value.tag !== undefined) {
      if (acc[key]){
        acc[key].push(value.item_id);
      }
      else {
        acc[key] = [value.item_id];
      }
    }
  });
  
  return acc;
}, {})
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the inner arrays are meant to contain objects, use `.reduce` to group the input objects into an object indexed by `item_id`, then transform that object into an array using `Object.entries`:

```js
const input = [ { 
    "web_devt": { 
      "item_id": "858850847",
      "tag": "web_devt" 
    } 
  },  
  { 
    "web_devt": { 
      "item_id": "1004644524",
      "tag": "web_devt" 
    } 
  },  
  { 
    "pdo": { 
      "item_id": "1056300113",
      "tag": "pdo" 
    },
     
    "php": { 
      "item_id": "1056300113",
      "tag": "php" 
    },
     
    "web_devt": { 
      "item_id": "1056300113",
      "tag": "web_devt" 
    } 
  },  
  { 
    "parallax scrolling": { 
      "item_id": "1087678088",
      "tag": "parallax scrolling" 
    } 
  },  
  { 
    "react": { 
      "item_id": "2435593852",
      "tag": "react" 
    } 
  },  
  { 
    "javascript": { 
      "item_id": "2435595088",
      "tag": "javascript" 
    } 
  },  
  { 
    "react": { 
      "item_id": "2465629468",
      "tag": "react" 
    } 
  } 
];
const outputObj = input.reduce((a, outerObj) => {
  Object.entries(outerObj).forEach(([key, { item_id }]) => {
    if (!a[key]) a[key] = [];
    a[key].push({ item_id });
  });
  return a;
}, {});
const output = Object.entries(outputObj).map(([key, arr]) => ({ [key]: arr }));
console.log(output);
```

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, Why use Object.entries not Object.values ? It's because Object.entries(obj) – returns an array of [key, value] pairs.  and Object.values(obj) – returns an array of values we can return key and value here right?

Comment: Sure, you can use either, it's up to you. If the key name is different from the `tag`, and you want the tag, then use `Object.values` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my try using `Array.reduce()` with a nested `Object.values()` and `Array.forEach()`:

```js
const input = [ 
  { 
    "web_devt": {"item_id": "858850847", "tag": "web_devt"} 
  }, 
  { 
    "web_devt": {"item_id": "1004644524", "tag": "web_devt"} 
  }, 
  { 
    "pdo": {"item_id": "1056300113", "tag": "pdo"}, 
    "php": {"item_id": "1056300113", "tag": "php"}, 
    "web_devt": {"item_id": "1056300113", "tag": "web_devt"} 
  }, 
  { 
    "parallax scrolling": {"item_id": "1087678088", "tag": "parallax scrolling"} 
  }, 
  { 
    "react": { "item_id": "2435593852", "tag": "react"} 
  }, 
  { 
    "javascript": {"item_id": "2435595088", "tag": "javascript"} 
  }, 
  { 
    "react": {"item_id": "2465629468", "tag": "react"} 
  } 
];

let res = input.reduce((acc, obj) =>
{
    Object.values(obj).forEach(({item_id, tag}) =>
    {
        acc[tag] = acc[tag] || {[tag]:[]}
        acc[tag][tag].push(item_id);
    });
    return acc;
}, {});

console.log(Object.values(res));
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper{max-height:100% !important; top:0}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response to my question. I tried this and it works.

Comment: @GLEN87 I'm glad to help, remember to vote-up the answers that helps you and to accept one of the answers.